# Generate Flag to check wheter join condition match or not - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to join 2 tables, table a and table b where b is a lookup table by left outer join. my question is how can i generate a flag that show whether match or not match the join condition ?

**The lookup table b for column id and country are always not null values, and both of them are the keys to join table a. This is because same id and country can have multiples rows in table a due to update date and posting date fields.

example table a

```
id country area
 1 China Asia
 2 Thailand Asia
 3 Jamaica SouthAmerica
 4 Japan Asia
```

example table b

```
id country area
 1 China Asia
 2 Thailand SouthEastAsia
 3 Jamaica SouthAmerica
 5 USA     America
```

Expected output

```
id country area Match
 1 China Asia Y
 2 Thailand SouthEastAsia Y
 3 Jamaica SouthAmerica Y
 4 Japan Asia N
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try

```
Select a.Id,
       a.Country,
       a.Area,
       Case When b.Id Is NULL Then "N" Else "Y" End as [Match]

From TableA a
Left Join TableB b on a.Id = b.Id And a.Country = b.Country
```

Comment: You make big assumption when checking matching based on id.

Comment: The lookup table b for column id and country are always not null values, and both of them are the keys to join table a

Comment: It doesn't matter if the schema for TableB is defined as NOT NULL. By using a Left Join you will force NULL values to be returned when the join condition is not fulfilled.

Comment: @lad2025 which is?